# Is it possible to convert SELECT-IN-SELECT query to a JOIN Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I need to delete a bunch of records from a table. I have found a query that will work to do the job, but I am told that sub-queries are not supported, but joins are.. Is it possible to convert the following query to a join. If so how?

```
SELECT * 
FROM PRODUCT 
WHERE PROD_NAME IN 
  (SELECT PROD_NAME 
    FROM PRODUCT 
    WHERE BRAND = 'Apt88' 
      AND NAME = 'Version' 
      AND VALUE IN ('3.7', '3.8'))
```

Any help appreciated,

Ted

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Yes. it is. Most easy would be to take your inner query, and `JOIN PRODUCT p2 ON p2.PRODUCT_NAME = PRODUCT.PRODUCT_NAME`. Select from `p2` in that case, you might want to add `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the proper equivalent:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM PRODUCT p join
     (SELECT distinct PROD_NAME 
      FROM PRODUCT 
      WHERE BRAND = 'Apt88' AND NAME = 'Version' AND VALUE IN ('3.7', '3.8')
     ) pn
     on p.prod_name = pn.prod_name;
```

Note the use of `distinct`.  If your rows are distinct (but not necessarily `prod_name`) then you can do:

```
SELECT distinct p.*
FROM PRODUCT p join
     PRODUCT pn
     on p.prod_name = pn.prod_name;
WHERE pn.BRAND = 'Apt88' AND pn.NAME = 'Version' AND pn.VALUE IN ('3.7', '3.8');
```

Comment: You are trying to avoid sub-queries by joining with a... sub-query. :D

Comment: @KouberSaparev . . . No, I'm trying to get a `join` equivalent to an `in` with a subquery.

Answer (score 2):

You are right - deleting from the same table you are selecting from is not supported in MySQL. But you can trick that with another subquery

```
DELETE FROM PRODUCT 
WHERE PROD_NAME IN 
(
    select * from 
    (
       SELECT PROD_NAME
       FROM PRODUCT
       WHERE BRAND = 'Apt88' AND NAME = 'Version' AND VALUE IN ('3.7', '3.8')
    ) x
)
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but how is this functionally different than simply `DELETE FROM PRODUCT WHERE BRAND = 'Apt88' AND NAME = 'Version' AND VALUE IN ('3.7', '3.8')`? (Not a criticism of your answer specifically; same question applies to use of subquery in original question.)

Comment: @Wiseguy, hint: `DELETE FROM PRODUCT WHERE BRAND = 'Apt88' AND NAME = 'Version' AND VALUE IN ('3.7', '3.8')` doesn't reference `PROD_NAME`.

Comment: @MarcusAdams I thought that was a redundant step, using `PROD_NAME` as an ID, but now I see. If multiple records have the same `PROD_NAME`, all of them will be removed even if only one of them matches the brand/name/value criteria. Right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can join the product table to itself. You just need to use two separate aliases to differentiate between the logically separate tables in the query:

```
SELECT p1.*
FROM PRODUCT p1
INNER JOIN PRODUCT p2 on p1.PROD_NAME = p2.PROD_NAME
WHERE p2.BRAND = 'Apt88' 
AND p2.NAME = 'Version' 
AND p2.VALUE IN ('3.7', '3.8')
```